# Displaying Error or alert message in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel. I want to display alert message. But i cannot display alert message once i hit url with localhost/social/alert. Please help me

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick observation, which url do you intend to visit?

Is it `localhost/social/alert` or `localhost/alert`?

Also, try this

```
@if (session('info'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session('info') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: localhost/social/alert this one url

Comment: Try out the suggestion I made. @GNTimilsina

Comment: I tried but it doesnot show anything. i think session is not started. Please suggest me.

Comment: Ah I think I know why, look at my next answer

Comment: Where is your next answer ?

Comment: Check it out now @GNTimilsina. Feel free to vote it up if it works.

Answer (score 0):

So in laravel 5.2, the errors, cookies, csrf tokens and so on are handled in the `web middleware`.

There are two ways to go about it.

Move your code into the web middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
   //code goes here
});
```

Move the classes from the `web middleware` in the `$middlewareGroups` variable in `app/http/Kernel` to `$middleware`

I prefer the first one